# Google Maps in AS2

Tags: flash, api, google-maps, actionscript, actionscript-2

I've got a Flash site. It's coded AS2 and I want to import Google maps into my site. How can I do this.

I created Google Maps Javascript API well. What comes next?

Is there a shorter way or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to use Google's AS3 library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/. However, using this is discouraged, as this version has been deprecated in favor of the newer JavaScript API.

Comment: thank you for answer but i dont understand, sorry. What can i do?

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna You had mentioned that you are working with a project that is written in AS2. AS2 was popular from 2003-2006, and since then, Adobe has deprecated AS2 (i.e.: removed their support and recommendation for this programming language, in favor of the newer AS3). Google developed an AS library that is used AS3, which, as of now, is the current and recommended language, since Adobe discourages usage of any previous version, and since far fewer Flash projects use AS2 or even AS1. Since it seems as though you are stuck with AS2, here is what I recommend. (see next comment)

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna (continued from previous comment) First of all, Google is deprecating their API for Flash, since the newest trends on the web are moving more toward HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript/AJAX, and away from Flash. Google will continue to operate (but not recommend or officially support) their Flash API until September 2, 2014. That is something to keep in mind, and eventually have your project (or at least this section) migrated to the new JavaScript version. Here is a third-party library for using Google Maps with AS2: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-flash-interface/